# Possibility to display current partner.id in odoo view

Tags: python, django, xml, model-view-controller, odoo

I want to get the current partner's id in my stock.picking view. I foud something like this

```
<field
      name="myId"
      domain="[('partner_id','=',id)]"
/>
```

but it's wrong.Is it even possible to have the current partner's id?

Comment: Try: `('partner_id.user_ids', '=', uid)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `domain` is used to apply filters when displaying existing records for selection.

To hide a field based on a record values you need to use `attrs` attribute and use the `invisible` value.

It is a mapping of attributes to domains, domains are evaluated in the context of the current row’s record, if True the corresponding attribute is set on the cell.

***Example:***

```
attrs="{'invisible': [('interval_type', '=', 'days')]}"
```

You can define a computed field to show the partner id field. Try the following code:

```py
@api.depends('partner_id')
    def get_partner_id(self):
        for record in self:
            if record.partner_id:
                record.raw_partner_id = record.partner_id.id

    raw_partner_id = fields.Integer(compute='get_partner_id')
```

To show the `stock.picking` ID, you just need to add `<field name="id"`/> in the view definition.

Comment: thanks, and what you think, is there a way to get the current partner_id when I am in stock.picking view. could it be done with context={"""}?

Comment: Do you need to show the integer `id` field in `stock.picking`?

Comment: yes, also. I must show the partner's id and the id of stock picking.

Comment: You can define a computed field, check my edit.